# UFT ObjectSpy unable to identify objects in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, hp-uft

I was trying to make ObjectSpy work with Chrome browser but its unable to identify objects.
Whenever trying to identify getting this: `WinObject("Chrome Legacy Window")`.

I tried reinstalling UFT and chrome and Microfocus extension for chrome but it didn't help.
I have downloaded extension from internet and its shows the version as **Micro Focus UFT Agent
2022.0.1.25**. My UFT version is **14.53**. I am not sure if its compatibility issue.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

UFT 14.53 is pretty old as far as supported browsers are concerned ([July 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Focus_Unified_Functional_Testing)), if possible I would suggest upgrading to the latest version (upgrades are included in the license).

Failing that you can try to remove the extension from Chrome and install the one that comes with your version of UFT (in `<UFT installation dir>/Installations`) although I'm not sure it will work with current versions of Chrome.